# How to load 'admin-ajax.php' in frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is the Javascript.

Javascript

`new AjaxUpload('#upload_btn', {
     action: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',`

Only works if you are logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins):

> `wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)` executes for users that are not logged in.
>   So, if you want it to fire on the front-end for both visitors and
>   logged-in users, you can do this:
>
> ```
>     add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
>     add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
> ```

Comment: Lack of attention, thank you. :D